# "Default FirebaseApp is not initialized" error occurs by using it in a static helper method in a module dependency

Tags: java, android, gradle, firebase-realtime-database

**Project structure:**

- Mobile app
- Things app
- Shared module

The shared module is linked as a dependency to the apps.

**Problem**

In my shared module, I've some common code like my `FirebaseManager`that easyfies the creation of new database entries - with static methods.

```
public class FirebaseManager
{
    /**
     * Saves a given object as child to the root
     * @param root Name of the root node
     * @param obj Object to save
     */
    public static void create(String root, Object obj)
    {
        DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(root);
        String id = database.push().getKey();
        database.child(id).setValue(obj);
    }
}
```

If I call now this creation method in an app, I'll get a stack trace with the following error:

> Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.example.
>   Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.

**What I tried - and not fixed my problem:**

- Called `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this)` on my `MainActivity.OnCreate(...) method.
- Added MainActivity's context as a prameter to my creation method
- Other stack overflow posts suggest, to add `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` to m apps' build.gradle file. This will lead to an weird "Multiple Dex Archive ..." error

**Update 1: Added gradle files**

- Project gradle:
  https://gist.github.com/tscholze/ad81ded78fc5d3a6481436cb3e8587e1
- shared module gradle:
  https://gist.github.com/tscholze/ecb8a860157d3a52b8a79b53f293f104
- Android Things grade:
  https://gist.github.com/tscholze/bdcd2efd5ee6fae1be4433838678e559

**Update 2**
It has to do something with my Android Things project. The code works fine in my "mobile" Android project.

Comment: Post both your Gradle files

Comment: Have you downloaded/included `google-services.json` in your project?

Comment: @tyczj Of course. The project's gradle: https://gist.github.com/tscholze/ad81ded78fc5d3a6481436cb3e8587e1 , the shared module gradle: https://gist.github.com/tscholze/ecb8a860157d3a52b8a79b53f293f104 , the app's gradle: https://gist.github.com/tscholze/bdcd2efd5ee6fae1be4433838678e559

Comment: @JohnO'Reilly yes. I tried it manually and by using the Android Studio wizard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two issues here:

1. The `apply plugin` line (which you currently have commented out) in `app-build.gradle` should go at the **bottom** of the file (see [Firebase instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#manually_add_firebase)). This is most likely what is causing your error at the moment.
2. You must use the version of Play Services that is bundled with your Android Things build (see [Google Services](https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/index.html#google-services) in the docs). You can find the version of Play Service bundled with each preview in the [Release Notes](https://developer.android.com/things/preview/releases.html).

Answer (score 0):

try calling `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this)` inside Application class's (class that extends Application) onCreate() method

Comment: I'm not able to find this class. I looked in all my app folders. There ist just my `MainActivity` classes. Could you please give me a hint where this file is located?

Comment: You have to create the class. Create a class which extends 'Application' class. then inside that class override onCreate() function and call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this) there. Also you need to register it in AndroidManifest.xml. Under <application> tag write android:name=".<class_name>"